# Getting error ',' expected. on ForkJoin and combineLatest in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to combine two observables and compare both values and output the width based on the results. 
I am following procedure from https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs#forkjoin

The Error is actually in this code

```
 .subscribe( (results) =>  {
```

I have also tried with this code but the error remains the same

```
.subscribe( ([res1, res2]) =>  {
```

Here is the code:

```
 ngOnInit() {
  forkJoin([this.sidenavService.lSidenavOpenSub$, this.sidenavService.rSidnavOpenSub$])
  .subscribe( (results) =>  { 
    if (results[0] == false && results[1] == false) {
      this.width = this.widthService.width100;
      debugger;
      console.log('noneOpen');
      } else if (results[0] == true && results[1] == false) {
      this.width = this.widthService.width100 - this.leftWidth;
      debugger;
      console.log('leftOpen');
    } else if (results[0] == true && results[1] == true) {
      this.width = this.widthService.width100 - (this.rightWidth + this.leftWidth);
      debugger  
      console.log('bothOpen');
    } else if (results[0] == false && results[1] == true) {
      this.width = this.widthService.width100 - this.rightWidth;
      debugger
      console.log('rightOpen');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missed the closing parenthesis at the end for `subscribe`

```
  .subscribe( (results) =>  { 
    if (results[0] == false && results[1] == false) {
      this.width = this.widthService.width100;
      debugger;
      console.log('noneOpen');
      } else if (results[0] == true && results[1] == false) {
      this.width = this.widthService.width100 - this.leftWidth;
      debugger;
      console.log('leftOpen');
    } else if (results[0] == true && results[1] == true) {
      this.width = this.widthService.width100 - (this.rightWidth + this.leftWidth);
      debugger  
      console.log('bothOpen');
    } else if (results[0] == false && results[1] == true) {
      this.width = this.widthService.width100 - this.rightWidth;
      debugger
      console.log('rightOpen');
    }
  }) // here ...................
```